# Flexbox equal column height set dominant column height?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have made this example:

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.flex-row .content {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x265" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col content">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my image on the left to be cropped but I want my content to dictate the overal height of the `.example` element.

Currently the image is dictating the overal height of the entire element. I want to image to be cropped to the size of the content that is in the right column. Is it do-able with my example?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194042/one-flex-item-sets-the-height-limit-for-siblings

Comment: Were my answer of any use?

Comment: I still need to test the browser support for IE with my current solution. But you said: `This overcome 2 bugs in IE, where one can't use calc in shorthand flex and the border-box issue to have padding inlcuded in the set width`, but I do not have any need for `calc` with my current solution so I am wondering if you are hinting at some other bugs perhaps?

Comment: No, the `calc` I used to reduce the padding from the width, or else the width is 60% + padding. If that is fine then no need to use it, if not, then that is the workaround for `box-sizing: border-box`, which is the 2nd bug I meant. The other option is to drop padding on the flex item and use a margin on its child.

Comment: May I ask why you keep an answer that doesn't work cross browsers the accepted one, when there is one's that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want your right column to set the overall height of `#example`

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.flex-row .content {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x265" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col content">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This stretches the image.

Comment: @Stephan-v should the image be at center? I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: @Stephan-v Do note, this does not work cross browsers

Comment: @LGSon for which browsers would this not work and why exactly? When using flexbox I do not care about browsers that do not support flexbox to begin with. If there are other concerns besides that, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephan-v I don't talk about browsers that does not support Flexbox. If you test this solution you find that it won't work properly in Firefox, IE11 and Safari 10.x, where they generally have issues with absolute positioned flex items. I have posted an answer with the best solution when it comes to browser support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: relative` on parent element and `position: absolute` on image and set `height: 100%`

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-row .content {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}
.image {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.image img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x265" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col content">some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use object-fit because it has terrible browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: The height is still way longer than the content that is within the right column.

Comment: This does not cover the left column.

Comment: You can add `width: 100%` also

Answer (score 1):

> I want my image on the left to be cropped but I want my content to
>   dictate the overal height of the `.example` element.

When using an `img`, what first comes to mind is `object-fit`, though since it has not the best browser support, here is one that has, making use of `background-image`.

Generally, when using `background-image`, one set the image source in the external CSS, though sometimes one want to set it in the markup, like one does when using an `img`.

An often overlooked possibility when this is needed, is to simply use the `style` attribute, which is no more complicated than the `src` attribute on the `img`, where one can set the source in markup like this: `style="background-image: url(...)"`

*I also used `flex-basis: calc(60% - 30px)`. This overcome 2 bugs in IE, where one can't use `calc` in shorthand `flex` and the `border-box` issue to have padding inlcuded in the set width.*

Stack snippet

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flex-row .content {
  flex-basis: calc(60% - 30px);
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500x265)">
    </div>

    <div class="col content">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you still need (or have to) use an `img`, here is one sample that work cross browsers.

Since several browsers, i.a. [Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418175/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-children-of-a-flex-container-in-safari/44418699#44418699) (appears to be fixed from v. 11 though) and IE, have issues with Flexbox and absolute positioned flex items, I here make use of `transform: translate` to provide a solution to center the image.

Stack snippet

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-row .image img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.flex-row .content {
  flex-basis: calc(60% - 30px);
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x265)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col content">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `backgound-image` property

```css
.example {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.flex-row .content {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #b7bdbb;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/500x265');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:50% 50%;
}

.image img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col image">
    </div>

    <div class="col content">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My url is not directly accessible. So I need to compose it within Javascript and set the style on the element through Javascript. If this can be done another way I would prefer it for performance reasons and to simplify my code.