# CSS Filter removes H1

Tags: html, css, overlay, css-grid, css-filters

I'm trying to overlay an h1 over an image, using Grid;
for better contrast, I thought about using `filter:brightness(80%)`
on the image, which, unfortunately, removes the h1 altogether.

Is there any workaround to this? ( without pasting in image URLs in CSS)
(`filter` is commented for you to apply and see)

```css
body{
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.gridcontainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
}

.griditem{
  background: black;
}

.headingcover{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  /* filter: brightness(80%); */
}
h1{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
  <div class="gridcontainer">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/7TGVEgcTKlY" alt="" class="headingcover">
    <div class="griditem b">b</div>
    <div class="griditem c">c</div>
    <div class="griditem d">d</div>
    <h1>Foxy</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you use any value for `filter` you create a new stacking order.

Comment: alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35871294/3597276

Comment: Add `z-index:1` to `h1`. It seems that `filter` causes the `img` create separate stacking context so it overrides sibling elements without `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

other than filter you can use 
text-shadow property of css for better contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index to your h1 to put it above your filter in the element stack.

```
h1 { 
    grid-column: 1/3; 
    grid-row: 1/2;
    z-index: 10;
}
```