# Flexbox and absolute positioning not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a button class with the following styles:

```css
.button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #f48120;
  color: #f48120;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.button::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -4px;
  content: '\f111';
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Enviar</button>
```

If I uncheck and then check again the "position: absolute"  attribute in the inspector, the circle gets aligned in the center. Is this a Blink/Webkit bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute elements wont get positioned by the parents aligns. Just position it with left and transform it to center it.

just a sidenote, there is no need to use `display: flex;` on the absolute element.

```css
.button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: deeppink;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  bottom: -4px;
  font-size: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I think this is more like a workaround, because according to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children) the styles should be working as I had them. You were right about using `display: flex` (I was trying to center the circle); `text-align: center` does the job.

Comment: @JuanS. My solution is not a workaround, thats how you position absolute items and have forever. The article you reference will only apply browsers that are compatible with it, I would guess the IE and Edge are in that category.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. I was confused about how the element was being positioned. `left` positions the element relative to its parent and `translate` relative to itself, which does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Four things to consider:

1. [Flex items that are absolutely-positioned do not accept flex properties from the parent](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). Because they are out-of-flow, absolutely-positioned children of a flex container are removed from a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) and return to a [*block formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting) (or other box model).
2. [HTML `<button>` elements cannot be flex containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276)
3. [Absolutely-positioned flex items may not be removed from the normal flow in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276).
4. [Center text over an image in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35871294/3597276)