# Place a text on top of an image

Tags: html, css, django, flexbox

I want to place an image in the center of my white page and add a title over it (the title would be larger than the image || also the title center must be the image center). The problem is that the title won't go on top of the image.

I use Django and bootstrap ^^

Here is the code :

HTML :

```html
<div class="col-md-7 white nopadding text-center">
            <div class="brand">
                Brand
            </div>
            <div class="heading">
                <img src="{% static '/eyemeet/hero.jpg' %}" class="hero">
                <div class="title ctr">Title</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.hero {
    width: 65%;
    height: auto;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.ctr {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

What happens currently :
[image]

**EDIT :**

I found the answer !! I hope it can help the ones who still wonder how to do it :) [Center text over an image in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871294/center-text-over-an-image-in-flexbox)

Comment: I think you need to add some more of your CSS because your provided code is working fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/17bofkqa/

Comment: I would use the image as a background image of the title

Answer (score 0):

Parent element has to be `position:relative` and then positioning will contain only inside this parent element

```
.heading{
  position:relative;
}
.title{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hero {
    width: 65%;
    height: auto;
}

.title {
    position:absolute;
    top:55%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width:100px;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-7 white nopadding py-3 text-center">
            <div class="brand py-2">
                Brand
            </div>
            <div class="heading">
 
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgetwallpapers.com%2Fwallpaper%2Ffull%2Ff%2F3%2Fa%2F807159-download-funny-cats-wallpapers-1920x1200-meizu.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" class="hero">
  <div class="title text-center ml-auto mr-auto ">Title</div>               
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It works, but the title is not centered. Is it possible to use % instead of px ? So that the title can be 50% from the top of the image

Comment: @Bonsaï check i edited my answer