# How to put img on bottom right corner in div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put a small icon on the bottom right corner and I need it to be responsive depending on whether it's a pc or or mobile.

```
    <style>
        .tdlr{
            background-image: url('img/TLDRback.png');
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding-top: 150px;
            margin-top: 100px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 450px;
        }

        .btmRght {
            height: 70px;
            width: 70px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -10px;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <section class="container-fluid text-center ">
        <div class="tdlr"> <img class="btmRght" src="img/TLDRbottomright.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: current issue]

Comment: One method you may want to consider: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35871294/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to `.tldr`.

`position: absolute;` positions an element relative to its nearest parent with `position: relative;`. When there is no such parent, it's positioned relative to the entire document.

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-ardinghelli-wy6x4?file=/index.html)

Comment: yes (to Distortum)  but in some cases you may also need to add `z-index:+9` to `.btmRight` or `z-index:+[#]`... if you want to make sure the img appears above other content... not needed in your example because the img is the only thing in the container using a background-image